# Embedded YouTube Video not working with Overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash, youtube

I'm having issues with a YouTube video breaking a jQuery slider when viewed on an Apple mobile device.  The slider uses a set width & height window that uses the overflow:hidden property.  It looks great in all browsers except for Apple devices where all of the slides are visible in a row as if the overflow:hidden property did not take effect.

Is there a way that I can fix this issue?  I'm stumped!  Thanks guys.

Link to site:  http://dwproductsllc.com/

Embedded video code:

```
<li>
<object width="409" height="257"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/0FGR-vPUWa8?hl=en&fs=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&playlist=0FGR-vPUWa8&controls=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/0FGR-vPUWa8?hl=en&fs=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&playlist=0FGR-vPUWa8&controls=0" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="409" height="257"></embed></object>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is now wonder the clip doesn't work on Apples devices; it is flash.

Now, normally this isn't a problem, because YouTube serves a HTML5 clip to the Apple devices.

I don't know why this isn't the case here - I'm guessing it is either because you recently uploaded it (perhaps it takes a while). And/or that you have the clip unlisted, maybe YouTube doesn't support HTML5 for those kind of clips.

I don't see any major faults with your code though (I would perhaps used a slightly different way). Try setting another clip in the slider and test to see if that works - then you can rule out your code and blame YouTube instead.

Comment: In order for Youtube to flip out the Flash embed for HTML5 you need to be using the iframe embed method. It will not work if you include the `<object>` tag directly on the page.

Comment: Maybe Apple devices do not allow hiding flash content!? Would be a security measure.

Comment: @Andrew Curioso Great point - however I am certain that I checked the YouTube page for the clip in the iOS Simulator, and the clip didn't show up. However, seems to be working now.

So - Go with an iFrame.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Of course, Flash was the issue.  It seems that the iPhone doesn't support the HTML5 iFrame yet though.  It showed up as a white slide.  They'll probably update it with iOS5 though.  Thanks!